# Get values of all units in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to be able to get all the values of units in an array using PHP. For example:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
```

This would return "1, 2, 3", but this

```
$array = array(5, 6, 2);
```

Would return "5, 6, 2".
This would work for more than three units in the array

```
$array = array("foo", "bar", "abc", "def")
```

would return "foo, bar, abc, def".
How could I do something like this?

Comment: What is the problem? Did you try something? I don't know php very much but what about simple `foreach` loop with iterating over the items and concatenate to them to a string?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Oh, I never thought about using a foreach loop! EDIT: Implode seems to work a lot better for me, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo implode ( ", " , $array );
```

Check out php-page:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php